# how to set default value for a column using a scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Year] [int] NOT NULL,
[Month] [int] NOT NULL,
[Fields] [xml] NOT NULL,
[NameFromXML] [nvarchar](1000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

in `Fields` column I stor XML like this:

```
<Employees>
   <Person>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <Name>Ligha</Name>
      <LName>Agha</LName>
   </Person>
</Employees>
```

Ok.I want persist value of `Name` element to `NameFromXML`.I write this function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetName
(
        @xml XML
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
   BEGIN
  RETURN @xml.value('/Employees[1]/Person[1]/Name[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
   END
GO
```

but when I write this code to add default:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Test_XML_Index_View  ADD CONSTRAINT  df_f  DEFAULT(dbo.GetName(Fields)) 
FOR namefromXML
```

I got this error:

> The name "Fields" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Do you actually need a default here or are you just trying to create a computed column? Can the column ever have anything other than the value you are trying to use as the default?

Comment: I think my question is so obvious what I need.I want a value from my XML column.I don't want default value for all of records.

Comment: Not sure what you are on about with "default value for all of records". Will rephrase. Can `NameFromXML` ever be updated independently of the value of the column `Fields`? If the answer is no you are using the wrong tool.

Comment: I didn't DV before, but I am now for the yelling comment.  If I had to guess I would say they downvoted because you were kind of rude to Martin when he asked you a polite question.  Or because what you want to do is a bad idea and you are kind of hostile about it.

Comment: @Rozhin - `I think my question is so obvious what I need` isn't exactly a co-operative phrase.  If you want to be belligerent and fight with people, there are much more fun places to do that than SO.  And also the bold capitalised comment.

Comment: @JNK: please read my question one more time.I describe my question from zero point to end point with all details.what I should add to my question that it become obvios. **Dems**: I don't fight with people.I just say it's obvios...please be fair

Comment: I did read it.  It sounds like you want a combination of a computed column and a default value.  The problem with a default based on a value in another column is if the value changes in the source field, the value in the defaulted field won't change correctly.  This is why Martin asked what he did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have it as a *computed column*, which will *always* be correct, and won't require any more maintenance effort:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetName
(
        @xml XML
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
, SCHEMABINDING
AS
   BEGIN
  RETURN @xml.value('/Employees[1]/Person[1]/Name[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
   END
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Year] [int] NOT NULL,
[Month] [int] NOT NULL,
[Fields] [xml] NOT NULL,
[NameFromXML] AS dbo.GetName(Fields) persisted
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into dbo.tbl (Year,Month,Fields)
select 1,1,'<Employees>
   <Person>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <Name>Ligha</Name>
      <LName>Agha</LName>
   </Person>
</Employees>'

select * from dbo.tbl
```

I had to add `SCHEMABINDING` to the function, in order for it to be treated as *deterministic*. That, in turn, allowed me to mark the computed column as `persisted`, which means it can, in turn, be indexed if needed.

Comment: Computed columns don't have to be persisted to be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to store redundant data for each row. What happens if somehow that name in the XML is changed? How do you take care to update the NameFromXML column? By using triggers? I can give you the advise, to just store data you need by using regular columns. Write insert/update stored procedures with will take the XML as a parameter, and insert data from it into the appropriate columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot chris.I have a table with 100000 records.I want to add redundant column to show XML values.and if some value changed this change reflect to that columns.what I can do for this?

Comment: @Rozhin - don't add redundant data. It just causes problems later. If you _need_ this data available at the DB level, surface it in a view if you absolutely must have it, or in the query itself where it's needed. Otherwise, generate it in the app from the original, _clean_ data.

Comment: mmmm.my problem is this XMLs are so big(every of them is about 50 KB).and when I want get report from them getting data from this XMLs is so time consumnig.

Comment: Usually if people store XML data in one column, but also store some information of the XML in extra columns, something went wrong ;) You should decide, whether to go the XML data in one column way, or store data that you need for further queries in regular data columns. If your problem is that you receive XML data from somewhere else, don't be "lazy" and just store in a single column but use store procedures to extract the xml data you need and insert these in to regular columns of your table...

Comment: No.the problem is is I haven't access to application.The application stores data in XML format.I have access to Database and I want solve this issue in database